# Why jQuery click event works only once?

Tags: jquery, events, click

I'm trying to create a "turn off the lights" effect with jQuery when a user clicks on the "Read More" button.

The issue is that it works just once, when the user clicks on Read More and the lights get turned off (a png semi-transparent background appears to overlay the current one). If the user clicks on "Close Text" the effect doesn't disappear.

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){

// Hide shadow

jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');

jQuery(".custom-read-more-toggle").on("click", function() { 

if( jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none') ) {
  jQuery(".shadow-class").css({background : 'url(/*PNG HERE*/)'});

 } else if (jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'url(/*PNG HERE*/)')){ 
jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');
}

});

});
```

.custom-read-more-toggle is the button for "Read More" while  .shadow-class is what appears when the user clicks on the button. If you click on .custom-read-more-toggle the class doesn't disappear from the DOM.

```
.shadow-class {
z-index: 99999999999999;
}
.dark-overlay {
background: url(/* PNG HERE*/);

}
```

I've tried other solutions posted here but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check like this:

```
if( jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background') == 'none' ) {
```

Instead of:

```
if( jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none') ) {
```

---

When used like `.css(prop,value)` it sets the property value. And when used like `.css(prop)`then it gets the property value.

Comment: Thank your for your answer but it still doesn't work :( , do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you missing a bracket in the first example?

Comment: @fabio Sorry I was outside. you should just use else part setting background-image (not else if)

Comment: Sorry, still not working. http://pastebin.com/sLUKPAdW (the png has been replaced in the example due to privacy issues)

Answer (score 0):

Use : if( jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background') == 'none' )

Answer (score 0):

**Cut your line of code**

```
   else if (jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'url(/*PNG HERE*/)'))

    { 
       jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');
    }

  and paste this

      else if (jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background')=='none')

    { 
       jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(".activ").css({background : 'url(/*PNG HERE*/)'});

jQuery(".custom-read-more-toggle").on("click", function() {
 if (!jQuery(".shadow-class").hasClass('activ');) {
  jQuery(".shadow-class").addClass('activ');
} else {
  jQuery(".shadow-class").removeClass('activ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : if(jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background-image') == 'none' )